# Some bugs in my python war card simulator

Tags: python, simulation, playing-cards

Here is the problem I am working on: write a function war() that simulates one game of war and returns a tuple containing the number of battles, wars, and two round wars.

For me, the hardest part of writing the function is when there were consecutive wars. This is where I messed up on.

Here is my code:

```
import random
def shuffleDeck():
    suits = {'\u2660', '\u2661', '\u2662', '\u2663'}
    ranks = {'2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8' '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A'}
    deck = []
    for suit in suits:
        for rank in ranks:
            deck.append(rank + ' ' + suit)
    random.shuffle(deck)
    return deck

def splitDeck(deck):
    splitdeck = []
    for i in range(0, len(deck)//2):
        splitdeck.append(deck[i])
        deck.remove(deck[i])
    return splitdeck

def dealCard(deck):
    if deck != []:
        card = deck[0]
        deck.remove(card)
        return card

def battle(card1, deck1, card2, deck2):
    values = {'A':1, '2':2, '3':3, '4':4, '5':5, '6':6, '7':7, '8':8, '9':9, '1':10,
          'J':11, 'Q':12, 'K':13}
    if values[card1[0]] > values[card2[0]]:
        deck1.append(card1)
        deck1.append(card2)
    elif values[card1[0]] < values[card2[0]]:
        deck2.append(card2)
        deck2.append(card1)

def tiebreaker(card1, deck1, card2, deck2):
    values = {'A':1, '2':2, '3':3, '4':4, '5':5, '6':6, '7':7, '8':8, '9':9, '1':10,
          'J':11, 'Q':12, 'K':13}
    FDdeck1 = [card1]
    FDdeck2 = [card2

    while len(deck1) > 2 and len(deck2) > 2:
        for i in range(0, 3):
            FDdeck1.append(deck1[i])
            FDdeck2.append(deck2[i])
        for i in range(-3, 0):
            deck1.remove(FDdeck1[i])
            deck2.remove(FDdeck2[i])

        i = random.randrange(len(FDdeck1)-3, len(FDdeck1))
        j = random.randrange(len(FDdeck2)-3, len(FDdeck2))
        newcard1 = FDdeck1[i]
        newcard2 = FDdeck2[j]

        if values[newcard1[0]] > values[newcard2[0]]:
            for card in FDdeck2:
            deck1.append(card)
        break

        elif values[newcard1[0]] < values[newcard2[0]]:
            for card in FDdeck1:
                deck2.append(card)
            break

        elif values[newcard1[0]] == values[newcard2[0]]:
            continue

    if len(deck1) < 2:
        for card in deck1:
            FDdeck1.append(card)
            deck1 = []
        for i in range(0, 3):
            FDdeck2.append(deck2[i])
        for i in range(-3, 0):
            deck2.remove(FDdeck2[i])

        i = random.randrange(len(FDdeck2)-3, len(FDdeck2))
        newcard1 = FDdeck1[len(deck1)]
        newcard2 = FDdeck2[i]

        if values[newcard1[0]] > values[newcard2[0]]:
            for card in FDdeck2:
                deck1.append(card)

        elif values[newcard1[0]] < values[newcard2[0]]:
            for card in FDdeck1:
                deck2.append(card)

        while values[newcard1[0]] == values[newcard2[0]]:
            for i in range(0, 3):
                FDdeck2.append(deck2[i])
            for i in range(-3, 0):
                deck2.remove(FDdeck2[i])

            j = random.randrange(len(FDdeck2)-3, len(FDdeck2))
            newCard2 = FDdeck2[j]

            if values[newcard1[0]] > values[newcard2[0]]:
                for card in FDdeck2:
                deck1.append(card)
            break

            elif values[newcard1[0]] < values[newcard2[0]]:
                for card in FDdeck1:
                    deck2.append(card)
                break

            elif values[card1[0]] == values[card2[0]]:
                continue

    if len(deck2) < 2:
        for card in deck2:
            FDdeck2.append(card)
            deck2 = []
        for i in range(0, 3):
            FDdeck1.append(deck1[i])
        for i in range(-3, 0):
            deck1.remove(FDdeck1[i])

        i = random.randrange(len(FDdeck2)-3, len(FDdeck2))
        newcard1 = FDdeck1[i]
        newcard2 = FDdeck2[len(deck2)]

        if values[newcard1[0]] > values[newcard2[0]]:
            for card in FDdeck2:
                deck1.append(card)

        elif values[newcard1[0]] < values[newcard2[0]]:
            for card in FDdeck1:
                deck2.append(card)

        while values[newcard1[0]] == values[newcard2[0]]:
            for i in range(0, 3):
                FDdeck1.append(deck1[i]) # I get an error index out of range
            for i in range(-3, 0):
                deck1.remove(FDdeck1[i])

            j = random.randrange(len(FDdeck2)-3, len(FDdeck2))
            newCard2 = FDdeck2[j]

            if values[newcard1[0]] > values[newcard2[0]]:
                for card in FDdeck2:
                    deck1.append(card)
                break

            elif values[newcard1[0]] < values[newcard2[0]]:
                for card in FDdeck1:
                    deck2.append(card)
                break

def war():
    values = {'A':1, '2':2, '3':3, '4':4, '5':5, '6':6, '7':7, '8':8, '9':9, '1':10,
          'J':11, 'Q':12, 'K':13}

    deck = shuffleDeck()
    countbattle = 0
    counttiebreaker = 0 

    playerA = splitDeck(deck)
    playerB = deck

    while playerA != [] and playerB != []:
        cardA = dealCard(playerA)
        cardB = dealCard(playerB)

        if values[cardA[0]] != values[cardB[0]]:
            countbattle += 1
            battle(cardA, playerA, cardB, playerB)
        elif values[cardA[0]] == values[cardB[0]]:
            counttiebreaker += 1
            tiebreaker(cardA, playerA, cardB, playerB)

    if playerA != []:
        print('PlayerA wins')
    elif playerB != []:
        print('PlayerB wins')

    return (countbattle, counttiebreaker)
```

I noted the line where I get the error. It is under the function tiebreaker. I don't understand why I get the error list index is out of range since deck1 is supposed to have at least 50 cards since the length of deck2 is equal to or less than 2 cards.

Another problem I have with the function is that I sometimes get nothing when I run it. I just get a blank space after I run it. For instance,

> > > war()

Besides, those two setbacks are there any other problems within the code. I checked it and everything seems fine but there might have been some parts that I overlooked. Thanks.

Comment: Please cut this down to a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and provide the full error traceback. `tiebreaker` seems very long and has some repetition, consider refactoring it into more, smaller functions.

Comment: you are missing the second square bracket on the 4th line in tiebreaker. you've got "FDdeck2 = [card2" when it should be "FDdeck2 = [card2]" without that second bracket python tries to interpret everything below it as being in the list, which obviously fails.

Answer (score -1):

further to my comment there are numerous errors:

```
import random

def shuffleDeck():
    suits = {'\u2660', '\u2661', '\u2662', '\u2663'}
    ranks = {'2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8' '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A'}
    deck = []
    for suit in suits:
        for rank in ranks:
            deck.append(rank + ' ' + suit)
    random.shuffle(deck)
    return deck

def splitDeck(deck):
    splitdeck = []
    for i in range(0, len(deck)//2):
        splitdeck.append(deck[i])
        deck.remove(deck[i])
    return splitdeck

def dealCard(deck):
    if deck != []:
        card = deck[0]
        deck.remove(card)
        return card

def battle(card1, deck1, card2, deck2):
    values = {'A':1, '2':2, '3':3, '4':4, '5':5, '6':6, '7':7, '8':8, '9':9, '1':10,
          'J':11, 'Q':12, 'K':13}
    if values[card1[0]] > values[card2[0]]:
        deck1.append(card1)
        deck1.append(card2)
    elif values[card1[0]] < values[card2[0]]:
        deck2.append(card2)
        deck2.append(card1)

def tiebreaker(card1, deck1, card2, deck2):
    values = {'A':1, '2':2, '3':3, '4':4, '5':5, '6':6, '7':7, '8':8, '9':9, '1':10,
          'J':11, 'Q':12, 'K':13}
    FDdeck1 = [card1]
    FDdeck2 = [card2] # here you missed the second square bracket

    while len(deck1) > 2 and len(deck2) > 2:
        for i in range(0, 3):
            FDdeck1.append(deck1[i])
            FDdeck2.append(deck2[i])
        for i in range(-3, 0):
            deck1.remove(FDdeck1[i])
            deck2.remove(FDdeck2[i])

        i = random.randrange(len(FDdeck1)-3, len(FDdeck1))
        j = random.randrange(len(FDdeck2)-3, len(FDdeck2))
        newcard1 = FDdeck1[i]
        newcard2 = FDdeck2[j]

        if values[newcard1[0]] > values[newcard2[0]]:
            for card in FDdeck2:
            deck1.append(card) # this line 
        break # and this line should be indented further

        elif values[newcard1[0]] < values[newcard2[0]]:
            for card in FDdeck1:
                deck2.append(card)
            break

        elif values[newcard1[0]] == values[newcard2[0]]:
            continue

    if len(deck1) < 2:
        for card in deck1:
            FDdeck1.append(card)
            deck1 = []
        for i in range(0, 3):
            FDdeck2.append(deck2[i])
        for i in range(-3, 0):
            deck2.remove(FDdeck2[i])

        i = random.randrange(len(FDdeck2)-3, len(FDdeck2))
        newcard1 = FDdeck1[len(deck1)]
        newcard2 = FDdeck2[i]

        if values[newcard1[0]] > values[newcard2[0]]:
            for card in FDdeck2:
                deck1.append(card)

        elif values[newcard1[0]] < values[newcard2[0]]:
            for card in FDdeck1:
                deck2.append(card)

        while values[newcard1[0]] == values[newcard2[0]]:
            for i in range(0, 3):
                FDdeck2.append(deck2[i])
            for i in range(-3, 0):
                deck2.remove(FDdeck2[i])

            j = random.randrange(len(FDdeck2)-3, len(FDdeck2))
            newCard2 = FDdeck2[j]

            if values[newcard1[0]] > values[newcard2[0]]:
                for card in FDdeck2:
                deck1.append(card) # this line
            break # and this line should be indented further

            elif values[newcard1[0]] < values[newcard2[0]]:
                for card in FDdeck1:
                    deck2.append(card)
                break

            elif values[card1[0]] == values[card2[0]]:
                continue

    if len(deck2) < 2:
        for card in deck2:
            FDdeck2.append(card)
            deck2 = []
        for i in range(0, 3):
            FDdeck1.append(deck1[i])
        for i in range(-3, 0):
            deck1.remove(FDdeck1[i])

        i = random.randrange(len(FDdeck2)-3, len(FDdeck2))
        newcard1 = FDdeck1[i]
        newcard2 = FDdeck2[len(deck2)]

        if values[newcard1[0]] > values[newcard2[0]]:
            for card in FDdeck2:
                deck1.append(card)

        elif values[newcard1[0]] < values[newcard2[0]]:
            for card in FDdeck1:
                deck2.append(card)

        while values[newcard1[0]] == values[newcard2[0]]:
            for i in range(0, 3):
                FDdeck1.append(deck1[i]) # I get an error index out of range
            for i in range(-3, 0):
                deck1.remove(FDdeck1[i])

            j = random.randrange(len(FDdeck2)-3, len(FDdeck2))
            newCard2 = FDdeck2[j]

            if values[newcard1[0]] > values[newcard2[0]]:
                for card in FDdeck2:
                    deck1.append(card)
                break

            elif values[newcard1[0]] < values[newcard2[0]]:
                for card in FDdeck1:
                    deck2.append(card)
                break

def war():
    values = {'A':1, '2':2, '3':3, '4':4, '5':5, '6':6, '7':7, '8':8, '9':9, '1':10,
          'J':11, 'Q':12, 'K':13}

    deck = shuffleDeck()
    countbattle = 0
    counttiebreaker = 0 

    playerA = splitDeck(deck)
    playerB = deck

    while playerA != [] and playerB != []:
        cardA = dealCard(playerA)
        cardB = dealCard(playerB)

        if values[cardA[0]] != values[cardB[0]]:
            countbattle += 1
            battle(cardA, playerA, cardB, playerB)
        elif values[cardA[0]] == values[cardB[0]]:
            counttiebreaker += 1
            tiebreaker(cardA, playerA, cardB, playerB)

    if playerA != []:
        print('PlayerA wins')
    elif playerB != []:
        print('PlayerB wins')

    return (countbattle, counttiebreaker)
```

and lastly there must be some condition you are not testing for that allows the program to enter a huge loop constantly between battle and dealcard.

Comment: I've commented the code exactly where the issues are, rather than trying to explain it all in one block at the top